# Store "this" in TypeScript class( or maintain this in other way )

Tags: javascript, class, typescript

Is there a way to store the value of "this" in a TypeScript class.

Something like this( what ive used before )

```
Car = function() {
    var _car = this;
    this.speed = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        _car.speed +2;
    }, 32);
}
```

//Id like to do the same in typescript....preferably using var( not () => {} )
 Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve lexical capture of 'this' in TypeScript using a var assignment, but I would not recommend it. Lexical capture of 'this' is completely unnecessary when you understand how the JavaScript 'this' mechanism actually works.

Lexical capture of 'this' in TypeScript is usually achieved with arrow functions, but that being said, here's a sample TypeScript class that illustrates all three different ways of achieving what you want:

```
class Car {
  speed: number

  constructor() {
    this.speed = 0
  }

  // lexical capture of 'this' with var 
  increaseSpeed1() {
    var _car = this
    setInterval(function() {
      _car.speed += 2
    }, 32)
  }

  // lexical capture of 'this' with arrow function
  // (a pretty way of doing the same as above)
  increaseSpeed2() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.speed += 2
    }, 32)
  }

  // binding to 'this'
  // (I consider this the proper way, when you really understand how 'this' works)  
  increaseSpeed3() {
    setInterval(function() {
      this.speed += 2
    }.bind(this), 32)
  }  
}
```

In `increaseSpeed1`, the _car object cannot be resolved within the callback to setInterval (even though the callback does have its own 'this' value), so the engine looks in the next available scope and finds the required declaration and value for _car within the scope of the increaseSpeed1 function. Here, _car has lexically captured the 'this' value of the Car class.

In `increaseSpeed2`, which uses the arrow function, the 'this' value of the setInterval callback is essentially thrown out, and the 'this' value from the scope of the increaseSpeed2 function (which is the same as the 'this' value of the Car class) is lexically adopted for the setInterval callback.

In `increaseSpeed3`, we ***bind*** to the 'this' value of the Car class. Binding to the 'this' value of the car class creates a new function from the setInterval callback that will execute in the context of the 'this' from the Car class. Like I said in the code example, this is the most proper way of achieving what you want while respecting how the JavaScript 'this' mechanism is intended to work.

Also note that should you decide that arrow functions are your preference, you can make the `increaseSpeed2` function even more compact by removing the braces around the callback function body (because there is only one line of code):

```
increaseSpeed2() {
  setInterval(() => this.speed += 2, 32)
}
```

Happy coding. Hope this helps!